# jQuery column hide

Tags: jquery, html-table, toggle

I have a drop down with the same name as column headers.

```
<select id='showHideColumns'>
<option value='-1'> Show all </option> 
<option value='GroupA'> GroupA </option> 
<option value='GroupB'> GroupB </option> 
</select>
```

My columns have same name as the value like `<td class='GroupA'> //data </td>`

How can I show/hide column using Jquery?

I only know uptill this much:

```
if($("#showHideColumns).val()=="GroupA")
$(".GroupA").toggle()
else if ($("#showHideColumns).val()=="GroupB")
$(".GroupB").toggle()
```

> Can I reduce ABOVE code :

I was hoping of something of the lines :
`($("#showHideColumns).val().toggle()` but not sure of this

If anyone could help me reduce above line that would really of great help.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.' + $('#showHideColumns').val()).toggle();` should do the trick.  you were close.

Answer (score 1):

Tyr this

```
if($("#showHideColumns").val() != -1)
      $("."+$("#showHideColumns").val()).toggle()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#showHideColumns').change(function() {
  $('table td').hide().('.'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

Set `'table td'` to be whatever selector is necessary to select ALL the columns. If you do not hide all the columns first, you will not have the other columns disappear when you select a certain column.